# Call a method from within a sibling method with parameters

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have followed the first steps tutorial from apple, and I have a working app that can read text and display it in a label on button click. When I hit enter the textfield is resigned and the keyboard disappears, and when I hit the button the `changeGreeting` method is invoked. I want to call the `changeGreeting` function in the function thats used when I hit enter which is `textFieldShouldReturn`.

I tried everything I could think of, and read a lot online but Im not sure how to deal with (id)sender as a param for example. How should I edit my code to call changeGreeting on textfield enter?

code below:

```
- (IBAction)changeGreeting:(id)sender {

    self.userName = self.textField.text;

    NSString *nameString = self.userName;
    NSString *endString = @"burp";
    int r = arc4random() % 74;

    if ([nameString length] == 0) {
        nameString = @"World";
    }
    NSString *greeting = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@, %@! Random String of numbers: %d", nameString, endString, r];
    self.label.text = greeting;
}

    - (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        // on enter the keyboard is removed, but I want the
        // changeGreeting method involed too, something like
        // [self changeGreeting]



    }
    return YES;
}
```

thanks in adv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have it.  Just ignore the `sender` parameter:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)theTextField {
    if (theTextField == self.textField) {
        [theTextField resignFirstResponder];
        // on enter the keyboard is removed, but I want the
        // changeGreeting method involed too, something like
        [self changeGreeting:nil]
}
```

Comment: ahhh, that :nil is a huge lifesaver, thanks, ill accept the answer in 7 minutes

Comment: @HansWassink Or you could pass `self` instead of `nil`, which might be more "correct".

Comment: Ah, somehow that makes more sense indeed. Confusing stuff Objective C, the syntax makes me daze :)

Comment: @HansWassink Yeah the `sender` is the control that sent the message and lets the action method test for various values within it (for example "is the checkbox selected").  In this case the action method doesn't use it, but it could be code to expect the `sender` to be the textfield and to use `sender` to get the text from the textfield directly.

Comment: Ah ok man, thanks for the extra info... It all starts to make sense, guess a lot of practicing lies ahead and we'll master this language too :D